# Theme-based character encoding issue

Tags: themes, encoding

I am getting a Swiss Standard German, which looks like the letter "B", that replaces "ss" in my copy.

When I test with plugins enabled/disabled using the 2017 theme the issue goes away. When I enable Bones theme, with plugins enabled/disabled, I get the strange character encoding.

Copy is not pasted from Word and is generated via the WP text editor.

I've verified proper collation in my database.

An example can be found in the first paragraph, looking for the word "express" or "regardless": http://photonew.rasdesignmedia.com/about-roger-aguirre-smith/

Comment: When you use special characters it's a good idea to escape them. For the character you mentioned, you would type `&#223;` or `&szlig;` into the text editor and the web browser would convert it to the actual character. Here's a complete list of HTML escape characters: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resides within the CSS. I found the style block below baked in to the base stylesheet. Font-feature-settings, "gives you control over advanced typographic features in OpenType fonts." "liga" refers to ligatures and dlig refers to discretionary ligatures. Both of which are included in OpenType font sets.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-feature-settings/

```
p {
        -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
        -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1, dlig=1";
        -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
        -o-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
        font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig";
    }
```